# Как перезагрузить Ngnix?

Tags: windows, nginx

Подскажите пожалуйста, как перезагрузить `nginx` в windows?
Пробовала в командной строке ввести следующую команду

```
c:\nginx> nginx -s reload
```

но это не сработало и вывело ошибку

> "Отказано в доступе".

Comment: Командная строка с правами администратора запущена?

Comment: @AndrewHobbit, думаю, можно сразу в ответ писать

Comment: да, в режиме администратора

Comment: и все равно отказано в доступе

Answer (score 2):

Все получилось когда я сделала таким образом:

1. Запускаем командную строку в режиме администратора
2. Заходим в каталог, nginx;
3. Останавливаем nginx командой `net stop nginx`;
4. Запускаем командой `net start nginx`;
   решение подсказано [здесь](http://www.f-notes.info/nginx:install_as_windows_service)

Comment: Только в этом случае необязательно заходить в каталог nginx. Если nginx стоит как сервис, то им можно управлять из любого места командной строки. И кстати, в этом случае можно перезапускать и через контрольную панель - через апплет управления службами.

Comment: Спасибо) учту на будущее)))

Comment: @newman а если nginx не состоит в переменной PATH?? То не получится управлять из любого места командной строки.

Comment: @LevBazdyrev *а если nginx не состоит в переменной PATH??* возможные варианты: указываем полные пути, добавляем в Path, создаем *батник*

Comment: @LevBazdyrev а зачем ему вообще там находиться-то? Командам net stop / net start  бинарник nginx вообще не нужен. А менеджер сервисов путь к нему из реестра возьмет.